# Why Redis Cache is not getting empty in my Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I am using Redis Cache in my Spring Boot application to store data of multiple rest API's.

I am clearing Redis cache on a regular interval using Spring Cron Jobs. The method is getting called at required time-slots.

I have verified the logs but the cache is not getting clear and hence it is showing the stale data.

The code where I'm trying to clear the cache.

```
public class CustomerDerivation {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("redisCacheMngr")
    CacheManager redisCacheMngr;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${redis.api.update.interval}")
    @CacheEvict(value = "redis-cache", allEntries = true, cacheNames = {"redis-cache"})
    protected void cacheEvict() {
        redisCacheMngr.getCache("redis-cache").clear();
        logger.info("Evicting ModelCache");
    }
}
```

Custom cache configuration code.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("cloud")
public class CacheConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory brRedisFactory() {
        return connectionFactory().redisConnectionFactory(env.getProperty("model_cache_name"));
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> brRedisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(brRedisFactory());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean(name = "redisCacheMngr")
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(brRedisTemplate());
        cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
        cacheManager.setTransactionAware(true);
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

How to fix the code to clear the redis cache ?

Comment: Do You have `@EnableCaching` annotation? to enable spring cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Have you enabled the cache using @EnableCaching annotation?
2) why are you using @CacheEvict and clear() in the same method? Both serves the same purpose. Use either one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

1. App is started with the according profile (ie. "cloud")
2. @EnabledCaching on your configuration
3. Avoid to mix @CacheEvict and the CacheManager bean, you have to choose one way for eviction
4. Extract the @Scheduled method in another "CronJobs" bean to avoid multiple annotations and AOP inside class issues.

Regards.

Comment: I have use @EnabledCaching annotation on my Application.java class that is my main class. I 'll follow your step 3 and will remove CacheEvict Annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Spring use Spring AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) to implement caching which means you must use `public` access level on your `cacheEvict()` method so it can be intercepted by AOP proxy. Otherwise it is like you never annotate your method with  `@CacheEvict`